# Console.log Immutable JS

Tags: javascript, console.log, immutable.js

So I was looking through some data and threw in a

```
console.log(data)
```

which printed out

```
List[1]
```

after drilling down a few times I was able to get to what I wanted but wasn't sure how to log it out...so I have

```
console.log(data.get(0).get('childItems').get(0).get('nestedItems').get(0).get('name'));
```

This is extremely long. Is there not a way to drill in with shorter syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can use the [`.toJS()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/toJS) method.

So in your case: `console.log( data.toJS() )`

```js
const obj = Immutable.fromJS( {
  name: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ],
} );
const arr = Immutable.fromJS( [ {
  name: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ],
} ] );

console.log( obj.toJS().name ); // Should return an array
console.log( arr.toJS().name ); // Should return undefined
console.log( arr.toJS()[ 0 ].name ); // Should return an array
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That was it. Much shorter! Thanks. Ill mark it as the answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: But how do I ultimatley just get 'name'?

`console.log(data.toJS('name'))` ?

Comment: `console.log( data.toJS().name )` ;)

Comment: That logs out undefined. However, when I do `console.log(data.toJS())` it logs out `[Object]`

Comment: Interesting. I updated my answer - but what happens if you do a `console.log( data.toJS()[ 0 ] )`?

Comment: That put me on the right path and I had to do this in order to get to it: `console.log(data.toJS()[0].childItems[0].nestedItems[0].name);`

Comment: Maybe because it is so deeply nested

Comment: Yes probably. It depends on how you created your structure.

Comment: .toSJ() isn't recommended though. Try to use it scarcely.